# How to find structure across many JSON strings?

Tags: arrays, json

I have a bunch of similar JSON strings, lets say like these:

```
{"a":"foo", "b":"bar"}
{"a":"foo_2", "c":"bar_2"}
{"d":"foo_3", "c":"bar_3"}
```

The ones I have are long, about a hundred elements each, some have subelements and arrays.

I'm looking for a way/tool to go through all of them and find out what the structure is that each of these strings would split/fit to.

So in this case I'm looking for result along the lines of:

```
{"a":"text", "b":"text", "c":"text"}
```

Comment: what do you mean? to get type of value of each object property?

Comment: I'm looking to find a structure that is superset of all the structures within all the JSONs. The type of the property isn't important.

Comment: "The type of the property isn't important" - so, what does `text` in `"a":"text"` mean?

Comment: Nothing. I was just trying to get the output to look as JSON as well. Can be anything.